# MySql: how to import csv with comma in decimals

Tags: mysql, csv

I've been searching for a solution to my problem but found none.

I have a text file (>150K rows), tab delimited.
Numbers with decimals have a comma.
My fields are set as FLOAT.

The problem is that MySql is expecting a dot as decimal separator, not a comma, so all decimals are just ignored.
I tried to use different characters set, or even try replacing the comma with dot during import, but with no luck.

My import step

```
USE stat; 
LOAD DATA LOCAL INFILE 'tbl_t1.txt' INTO TABLE `tbl_t1`
FIELDS TERMINATED BY '\t' LINES TERMINATED BY '\r\n' IGNORE 1 LINES;
```

My raw data

```
Partno                  grossw  netw     ......up to 132 col
Item1                   1,4753  1,1325
Item2                   0,1673  0,0184
Item3                   2,1357  2,0361
```

Once imported I get

```
Item1                   1   1      .........
Item2                   0   0
Item3                   2   2
```

When trying below code I get zero rows, my table is emptied

```
USE stat; 
LOAD DATA LOCAL INFILE 'tbl_t1.txt' INTO TABLE `tbl_t1`
FIELDS TERMINATED BY '\t' LINES TERMINATED BY '\r\n' IGNORE 1 LINES
(@col1) SET grossw = REPLACE(@col1, ',' , '.');
```

**UPDATE**
I found why the table is emptied, the issue is that I have 132 columns in the table, and @col1 handle just 1 column. My above was just an example.
I need to investigate more.

Any help is very much appreciated.
Thanks.

Comment: try to convert it like this:
   ** USE stat; 
    LOAD DATA LOCAL INFILE 'tbl_t1.txt' INTO TABLE `tbl_t1`
    FIELDS TERMINATED BY '\t' LINES TERMINATED BY '\r\n' IGNORE 1 LINES;
    (@col1, @col2, @col3)
    set
     grossw = REPLACE(@col2, ',' , '.'),
     netw   = REPLACE(@col3, ',' , '.');**

Comment: Hi Bernd, tha table is emptied with your example

Comment: I have zero rows now :-(